# Wrong Node.js version is being detected by npm although it is not present in my machine

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Every time I run `npm run build:ssr` in angular CLI it gives me this error:

> `Node.js version v13.14.0 detected`.

I have checked everywhere in my ubuntu but nodejs version `13.14.0` is not there.

**Edit:** When I run `node -v` it returns `v16.15.0`.

Comment: Are you running WSL or WSL2 on Windows, with Ubuntu installed? I had a similar issue, and it was because I had Node.js installed on Windows also, and npm was using the windows install of Node.js. Uninstalling Node.js from windows fixed the issue.

Comment: @RyanWhite No. Just pure ubuntu.

Comment: By the way I have solved the issue by manually running the commands in package.json file.